# if condition in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query based on the the true/false value of a variable: tec

```
sigDB.find({
        $and: [
            { platform: platform? platform : '7x50' },
            { category: category? category : 'CPM' },
            { level: tec? { $gte: 1} : { $gte: 3}}
        ]
    }, {sort: sort}, function(err, cursor) {
        if (err) { console.log('ERRROROROROROROR') }
        else {
            cursor.toArray(function(err, rec) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('something is fishy')
                } else {
                    res.json(rec);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

When tec equals to false, I would expect that the level is selected as {$gte: 3}, however, the result comes back differently... I did try putting it as `level: {$gte: 3}` and it worked, so it must be something to do with that condition statement... I just don't know what is wrong...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tried your code out and it worked fine for me. Are you sure that the value for `tec` is being set correctly?

Comment: Ah ha... the boolean value of variable tec becomes type string on server side, I had to convert it to boolean and it worked. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it to work.